# Is there a perl module equivalent to python's optparse.OptionParser?

Tags: perl, optional-parameters

I have a new script that I need to write in perl, to leverage our perl codebase (no, I can't convert it, not yet anyway). Our coding standards dictate `Getopt::Long::GetOptions()` but I realize my option handling would be greatly improved and simplified if I could just drop python's optparse.OptionParser into it. The things I like in python: validation of inputs, both formats and required/optional, and auto help string generation based on argument config.

Any tips? I know I could roll my own, but I'd rather use someone else's work if it's already been done.

Comment: curious to know why you want to improve and simplify option handling in an existing code base?

Comment: @ysth good question. It's a new script for an existing code base - I threw that in there to not have people ask me to port it. My lack of clarity has been edited. thanks

Comment: In this case App::Cmd might be right up your alley.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The canonical tool is [Getopt::Long](http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long). It's not "declarative" as such. Is there some specific behavior you are trying to replicate?

**EDIT**: For more power, you might be interested in [App::Cmd](https://metacpan.org/module/App::Cmd) or parts of it (see also [App::Cmd::Tutorial](https://metacpan.org/module/App::Cmd::Tutorial)).

Internally this uses [Getopt::Long::Descriptive](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Long::Descriptive) which seems to meet most of your requirements. This might be especially useful for you because internally it uses `Getopt::Long` and [Params::Validate](https://metacpan.org/module/Params::Validate), so it might be very easy to move your current code base but now have validation.

Comment: Yeah, I already use that (edited question to reflect that). OptParser does a lot more, including validation, and generating help text based on the options.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of options in the [GetOpt](https://metacpan.org/search?q=getopt) namespace on CPAN.

[GetOpt::Std](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) and [GetOpt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) are both core modules.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is: [Getopt::optparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::optparse) (note: I'm the author of this package)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think that there's anything that this answer can improve. The OP asked for a Perl module that acts like a Python module, so @mhearse wrote one, submitted it to CPAN, and posted the link.  Done and done.

Comment: New features since OP.  Both single dash and double dash opts.  Actions: append and count.  Lastly I'm proud to have added callbacks.  Current version 1.2.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Answer (score 0):

[MooseX::Getopt](http://p3rl.org/MooseX%3a%3aGetopt) and [MooX::Options](http://p3rl.org/MooX%3a%3aOptions) are, well... options. Both work similarly, and both use Getopt::Long::Descriptive under the hood, integrating it with a class to provide advanced validation and defaulting as well as help text. Then you just use the `new_with_options` constructor and you get an instance of the class with all of its slots filled in from the commandline.